# Rails 3 JS remote link opens up and printed instead of executed

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have the following link

```
<%= link_to "Comment", new_blog_post_comment_path(@blog_post, format: :js), 
remote: true,  id: 'new_comment_link', class: 'btn' %>
```

When pressed, instead of executing new.js, my browser displays the text of new.js.
This happens even if new.js is empty, or just contains `alert('lol');`, so I'm fairly certain its not a JS error

This is the original new.js code, but I dont think it matters

```
$("<%= escape_javascript(render(:file => 'comments/new.html.erb')) %>")
.insertAfter('#blog_post'); // Insert the comment form before the first comment
$('#new_comment').slideDown();
$('#new_comment_link').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to wrap the code in view with script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("<%= escape_javascript(render(:file => 'comments/new.html.erb')) %>")
  .insertAfter('#blog_post'); // Insert the comment form before the first comment
  $('#new_comment').slideDown();
  $('#new_comment_link').hide();
</script>
```

Comment: I dont think it works like that... Anyway I tried it and it didn't work, it just gets printed along with the <script> tag